# Extract (unconcatenate) cell value in Excel

Tags: excel

I wish to split a cell value
The cell value will be in the form of `###x###`
Where `#` is a `0`-`9` number.
Also, the number of places can vary so it could be `###x####` or `####x####`
This makes me unable to use `LEFT` or `MID` function

The common thing is the two numbers I want to extract separately are joined by `'x'`

I tried using search function but could not find an answer.

How can I do this? With or without VBA? Thanks!

Comment: why not something like `=LEFT("123xABC", FIND("x", "123xABC") - 1)`? There is no need for vba or anything. This just a simple string and it is trivial to find a substring that's just an 'x'.

Comment: I sometimes wonder whether people even bother to look at the functions Excel has under the category "Text".

Comment: Alternately, you could use the Text to Columns feature -> Delimited -> Other character x -> Finish

Comment: Agree with @Cor_Blimey. You better off using `Text to Columns`. Don't recreate or formularize something that is built in in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your string is in the `A1` field.

You may use either `FIND` or `SEARCH` function to find the position of the `'x'` character.

```
=FIND("x", A1)
```

You get the first number by taking the characters from the left:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("x", A1) - 1)
```

You get the second number by taking the characters after until the end:

```
=MID(A1, FIND("x", A1)+1, 999)
```

(Of course, the parameter separator is according to your setting, so you may need to replace all the commas by semicolon or so.)